# What pads are compatible?

Tags: brakes

I have Tektro R320 Calliper brakes on my bike:

http://planet-x-bikes.co.uk/i/q/BCTKTR320/tektro_r320_brake_caliper

It's time for some new pads.

However, the ones on this appear to be all in one, bolt straight into the pad on the calliper.

If I look on wiggle, my usual online component supplier, there are lots of blocks for cartridges, or blocks like this:

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/swissstop-flash-pro-green-high-performance-blocks/

But not so many options that look like what is in the Tektro OEM.

How do I know what I can fit? what's compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like standard Shimano-type cartridge brakes. <strike>No need for new blocks, just get a set of pads.</strike>
I recently got these and they are really good - far better than the standard shimano ones: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/kool-stop-dura-aceultegra105-pair-of-cartridge-inserts/

Go for the salmon if you have non-carbon rims.

EDIT: I seems your brakes do not in fact have cartridges but the brake pad is a single piece that connects directly to the caliper arm. The dura-style cartridges (like the ones you linked to) will fit on your calipers and is a worthwhile upgrade. You will be able to more cheaply and easily replace pads and have a wider choice.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer to working out proper compatibility, but, wiggle customer support inform me that the swissstop green cartridges are compatible with my callipers. From this I draw the (semi) logical conclusion that if the block is design to work with a calliper brake, then it's compatible.

The issue then is one of weight/aerodynamics as to whether or not *you* want it on *your* bike. Reading, people seem to find that the Shimano ultegra cartridges paired with the swissstop pads makes an excellent combination. Supposedly the ultegra cartridge is lighter and more aero and applies the block more smoothly. And the swissstop pads are supposed to be great pads.

Comment: From a weight/aero perspective the difference is negligible but the pairing of a dura-style cartridge with quality (kool-stop or swissstop) pads is definitely the  way to go. You will probably find that shimano ultegra/dura-ace cartridges will be slightly better quality than the other makes.